# Обработчик mousemove в canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Хотел сделать обработчик при наведении на сектор диаграммы, но чтобы не делал в итоге canvas вообще не отрисовывается, вот приблизительный код:

```
window.onload = function() {
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var size = drawingCanvas.height;
    var n = 5; //Число секторов
    var rad = 2/n*Math.PI;
    var start = 3*Math.PI/2;
    var r = size/2;
    var colorTable = ['#DC3912','#FF9900','#FFF804','#66AA00','#6BE5F3','#3366CC','#990099','#DD4477', '#DC3912','#FF9900','#FFF804','#66AA00','#6BE5F3','#3366CC','#990099','#DD4477'];

for (var i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
    //сектор
    context.fillStyle = colorTable[i-1];
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(drawingCanvas.height/2, drawingCanvas.width/2);
    context.arc(drawingCanvas.height/2, drawingCanvas.width/2,size/2/100*80,start+rad*(i-1),start+rad*i,false);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}

// пишем текст
context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
context.font = '20pt Tahoma';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.fillText(text, r,r);

//context.onmousemove = mousemove;
// Функция вызываемая в момент когда курсор перемещается в облости холста
       setInterval(function(){
function mousemove(evt) {
    var mouseX = evt.pageX - context.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.pageY - context.offsetTop;
    for (var i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
         var a1 = start+rad*(i-1);
         var a2 = start+rad*i;
             if((mouseX-r)*(mouseX-r)+(mouseY-r)*(mouseY-r)<r*r && mouseY>Math.tan(a1)*mouseX+r && mouseY>Math.tan(a2)*mouseX+r){
             text = i;
             }
    }
}},1000 / 60);
```

}}

И сама канва: <canvas id='chart1' width='316' height='316'></canvas>

Хочу сам разобраться без использования фреймворков.

Comment: @Кирилл Туровников огромные куски кода очень нежелательно скидывать в вопрос, лучше вырезайте самое важное.

Comment: @Кирилл Туровников так лучше)

Comment: Да код криво вставился сначала, уже исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи, товарищ!

Не понял я, как ты хотел искать точку в секторе и по этому переделал основной механизм:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('chart1');

    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
        var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var size = drawingCanvas.height;
        var n = 5; //Число секторов
        var rad = 2/n*Math.PI;
        var start = -.5 * Math.PI;
        var r = centreX = centreY = size/2;
        var colorTable = ['#DC3912','#FF9900','#FFF804','#66AA00','#6BE5F3','#3366CC','#990099','#DD4477', '#DC3912','#FF9900','#FFF804','#66AA00','#6BE5F3','#3366CC','#990099','#DD4477'];

        for (var i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            //сектор
            context.fillStyle = colorTable[i-1];
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(r, r);
            context.arc(r, r, r, start+rad*(i-1),start+rad*i,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
        }

        text = 'текст';

        // пишем текст
        context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        context.font = '20pt Tahoma';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.textBaseline = 'middle';
        context.fillText(text, r,r);

        drawingCanvas.onmousemove = function(evt) {
            var mouseX = evt.pageX - drawingCanvas.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = evt.pageY - drawingCanvas.offsetTop;

            var xFromCentre = mouseX - centreX;
            var yFromCentre = mouseY - centreY;
            // теорема пифагора)
            var distanceFromCentre = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( Math.abs( xFromCentre ), 2) + Math.pow( Math.abs( yFromCentre ), 2));

            if(distanceFromCentre > r) return;

            // угол относительно центра (начинаем с 12 часов)
            var clickAngle = Math.atan2(yFromCentre, xFromCentre) - start;
            if ( clickAngle < 0 ) clickAngle = 2 * Math.PI + clickAngle;
            clickAngle = clickAngle + start; // небольшой хак

            for (var i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
                if(clickAngle >= start+rad*(i-1) && clickAngle <= start+rad*i) {
                    console.log(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>

<canvas id='chart1' width='316' height='316'></canvas>
```

Вся суть сводится к тому, что нам нужно определить угол поворота точки (мышки) относительно центра окружности и проверить, какому сектору эта точка принадлежит, т.е. с точки начала сектора по точку конце сектора.

Почаще бы таких вопросов относительно canvas'a :)

Comment: Спасибо, работает :) Я просто определял принадлежность к сектору области в условии 3 уравнениями: линий и окружности,видимо в чем-то ошибся, т.к. не видел результата работы скрипта. Да и canvas с js мало занимался, а тут возникла необходимость динамического построения ряда диаграмм.

Comment: @Кирилл Туровников отладку производите с помощью консоли (ctrl_shift+k/j/i) и метода [console.log()][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

Comment: Да я уже понял, сам с этим сталкивался, а тут не сообразил.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не нужно вызывать функцию `mousemove` каждые сколько-то там миллисекунд. Она должна быть обработчиком события `onmousemove` вашего `canvas`. Я вижу, вы пытались так сделать, но допустили ошибку: обработчик нужно вешать не на `context`, а на `drawingCanvas`.

Во-вторых, каждый раз, когда вы что-то рисуете на `canvas`'е, новое изображение накладывается на предыдыдущее, поэтому нужно перерисовывать изображение (или часть его). То есть, каждый раз, когда вы по `mousemove` рисуете надпись, нужно сначала перерисовать диаграмму, иначе следующая надпись наложится на предыдущую.

В-третьих, у вас нигде не объявляется и не инициализируется переменная `text`, поэтому ваш скрипт вылетит на строке `context.fillText(text, r,r);`. В связи с этим совет - смотрите на вывод консоли в инструментах разработчика вашего браузера (в Chrome, например, их можно вызвать кнопкой F12, в Firefox лучше установить Firebug), там пишется много полезной для отладки информации.

В-четвёртых, у вас что-то не так с определением, в какой сектор попал курсор. После исправления всех предыдущих ошибок упорно выводится число 4.