# Canvas События с мышью

Tags: canvas

Здравствуйте,прошу помощи в следующем:
Необходимо сделать анимацию, чтобы в заданной области (квадрат), объект (круг)произвольно отскакивал от курсора мыши, не вылетая за пределы заданной области.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Тени и простенькая анимация</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var canvas, ctx, w, h;

var ball = {
    x : 50,
    y : 100,
    r : 15,
    vx : 0,
    vy : 0
};
var count = 0;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    ctx.font = "18px Times-Roman";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

setInterval(function() { ctx.clearRect(1, 1, w - 2, h - 2);

    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;
    ball.vx *=1;

    ball.vy *= 1;
    ball.vy += .55;
    if (ball.y + ball.r > h - 15) {
        count++;
        ball.y = h - 15 - ball.r;
        ball.vy = -Math.abs(ball.vy);
    }

    if (count >= 1) { ball.vy *= 0.99; } if (count == 1) {
    ball.vx =5; } if (ball.x+ball.r > w - 15) { ball.x = w - 30; ball.vx = -Math.abs(ball.vx); } if (ball.x < 30) { ball.x = 30; ball.vx = -ball.vx; }

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillText("Count: " + count, 250, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.translate(ball.x, ball.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, ball.r * 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

},25);

</script>

</head> 
<body onload="init()"> 
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"> error </canvas> 
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLQwb/

Comment: @Гарри92, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Сделал что объект в этой области перемещается, но не знаю как сделать, чтобы он от курсора отскакивал рандомно.Подскажите event

Comment: @Гарри92 пример в студию :) На его основе мы как раз и предоставим пример.

Comment: @Гарри92 кстати было бы неплохо еще и язык программирования указать. Нет, я, конечно,понимаю, что речь скорее всего идет о JavaScript, но [мало ли][1]

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Гарри92 перенес ваши комментарии в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите обработчик события [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousemove) для вашего `canvas`'а. В обработчике [получаете кооринаты мыши](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.clientX) на `canvas`'е, определяете, [попадает ли курсор в круг](http://borlpasc.narod.ru/docym/le/pract/misk/5.htm). Дальше изменяете направление движения круга. Аналогично, используя [несложные](http://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/p_line1/) [формулы](http://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/line/), определяете, пересекает ли ваш круг границы области и, если пересекает, меняете направление его движения по [вот этим формулам](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=72856). Формулы для отражения можно сильно упростить, если предположить, что границы области строго вертикальные и горизонтальные. В этом случае достаточно поменять знак у соответствующей составляющей вектора скорости круга.

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvas, ctx, w, h;

var ball = {
    x : 50,
    y : 100,
    r : 15,
    vx : 0,
    vy : 0
};
var count = 0;
var mouseActive = false;
var start = -.5 * Math.PI;


function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    ctx.font = "18px Times-Roman";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);


    canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        mouseActive = false;
    }, false);


    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        mouseActive = {
            x: e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
            y: e.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top
        };
    }, false);
}

setInterval(function() { 
    ctx.clearRect(1, 1, w - 2, h - 2);

    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;
    ball.vx *=1;

    ball.vy *= 1;
    ball.vy += .50;
    if (ball.y + ball.r > h - 15) {
        count++;
        ball.y = h - 15 - ball.r;
        ball.vy = -Math.abs(ball.vy);
    }

    if (count >= 1) {
        ball.vy *= 0.99; 
    } 
    if (count == 1) {
        ball.vx =5; 
    } 
    if (ball.x+ball.r > w - 15) { 
        ball.x = w - 30; 
        ball.vx = -Math.abs(ball.vx); 
    } 
    if (ball.x < 30) {
        ball.x = 30;
        ball.vx = -ball.vx; 
    }



    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillText("Count: " + count, 250, 50);

    if(mouseActive) {
        // если шарик касается, то отпружиниваем его
        var x0 = mouseActive.x - ball.x;
        var y0 = mouseActive.y - ball.y;

        if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x0, 2) + Math.pow(y0, 2)) < ball.r * 2) {

            if(mouseActive.x < ball.x)  {
                ball.vx = 10;
            }
            else {
                ball.vx = -10;
            }

            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        }
    }

    ctx.translate(ball.x, ball.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, ball.r * 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}, 25);
```

Вам остается только правильно отразить по формулам @fori1ton

Подсказка: нахождение угла можно подглядеть в этом вопросе: [Обработчик mousemove в canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238719/javascript-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-mousemove-%D0%B2-canvas)

Comment: Огромное спасибо lampa)))